# Difference between group_by() then count() and just count()?

Tags: r, dplyr

1. How column name is formed for both approaches?
2. Which approach is considered optimized & why?

[image]

Comment: You can use function `microbenchmark` from the package of the same name to time the two forms. Tip: the second is around 1.7 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Function `count()` calls for `tally()` which creates column named `n`. See source of `tally()` in `dplyr` package.
2. Function `count()` already contains `group_by`. See source of `count()` in `dplyr` package. So your second variant is optimized. You can see it through the usage of microbenchmark as recommended by Rui Barradas in comments.
3. Applying`group_by` to `tibble` objects is adding plethora of attributes / inherits from `grouped_df` connected so memory usage is increased as well.

Supporting script (goes out to Rui Barradas):

```
    states_srs <-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clauswilke/dviz.supp/master/data- 
           raw/US_regions/US_regions.csv")
    library(dplyr)
    library(microbenchmark)
    microbenchmark(w_gr <- states_srs %>% group_by(region) %>% count(), times = 1000L)
    # mean time: 2.5 milliseconds

    microbenchmark(wout_gr <- states_srs %>% count(region), times = 1000L)
    # mean time: 1.7 milliseconds

    str(w_gr)
    # Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
    # inherits grouped_df 
    help("grouped_df")

    str(wout_gr)
    # Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
    # does not inherit grouped_df
```